# React Router - Nesting routes does not seem to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We would expect Master to appear in all the views (and possibly further nesting if needed. However, nothing renders on the browser. The App component is rendered in index.js as is the standard in any ReactJS app.  Am I not following the correct nesting process?

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    );
  }
}

const Master = (props) =>(
        <div>
            <h2>{'TutsPlus - Welcome to React Nested Routing App'}</h2>
            <Menu />
            {props.children}
        </div>
)

const Menu = () => {
    return(
        <section>            
            <ul>
                <li>{'Home'}</li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/view1">{'View1'}</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/view2">{'View2'}</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    )
};

const View1 = () => {
    return(
        <h3>{'Welcome to View1'}</h3>
    );
};
 
const View2 = () => {
    return(
        <h3>{'Welcome to View2'}</h3>
    );
};

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route component={Master} path="/">
            <Route component={Home} path="/home"></Route>
            <Route component={View1} path="/view1"></Route>
            <Route component={View2} path="/view2"></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this since Master component always want to show to the user.

Demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-fast-wnbem?file=/src/App.js:231-515

```
      <Router>
        <Route path="/">
          <Master>
            <Route component={Home} path="/home"></Route>
            <Route component={View1} path="/view1"></Route>
            <Route component={View2} path="/view2"></Route>
          </Master>
        </Route>
      </Router>
```

or Move our child route to the Master component like below for support nested routing.

```
 <Router>
    <Route component={Master} path="/"></Route>
  </Router>
```

---

```
const Master = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h2>{"TutsPlus - Welcome to React Nested Routing App"}</h2>
    <Menu />
    <Route component={Home} path="/home"></Route>
    <Route component={View1} path="/view1"></Route>
    <Route component={View2} path="/view2"></Route>
  </div>
);
```